# Switching a greaterthan/lessthan

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, methods

I am working on compacting some code, right now I have 4 methods that all do almost the exact same thing except the for loops are modeled a bit differently. I'm passing int's `up`, `down`, `right`, and `left` as parameters to this compact method, which coincides with the 4 methods I used to have.

By passing 1 for one of the parameters and 0 for the rest, I am able to do different this in a single loop, I'm just having trouble with switching a < or > sign.

This is the line of code I'm trying to work with:

```
for (int i = (right*3)+(up*3); i <= (left*3)+(down*3); i= i + (left) + (down) - (up) - (right)) {
```

Everything works except I need to switch the `i <= (left...` part to `i >= (left...` if `right == 1`, is there a way in Java to do this in for for loop?

If this isn't possible I could make 2 different for loops, I just don't like having almost identical code being repeated.

Thanks!

Edit: Here are the 4 methods:

```
public boolean moveRight() {
    boolean didMove = false;
    for (int a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i != 3) {
                    if (valueArray[i + 1][j] == 0  && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i + 1][j] = valueArray[i][j];
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    } else if (valueArray[i + 1][j] == valueArray[i][j] && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i + 1][j] = valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        Score += valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return didMove;
}

public boolean moveLeft() {
    boolean didMove = false;
    for (int a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    if (valueArray[i - 1][j] == 0 && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i - 1][j] = valueArray[i][j];
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    } else if (valueArray[i - 1][j] == valueArray[i][j] && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i - 1][j] = valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        Score += valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return didMove;
}

public boolean moveDown() {
    boolean didMove = false;
    for (int a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (j != 3) {
                    if (valueArray[i][j + 1] == 0 && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i][j + 1] = valueArray[i][j];
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    } else if (valueArray[i][j + 1] == valueArray[i][j] && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i][j + 1] = valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        Score += valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return didMove;
}

public boolean moveUp() {
    boolean didMove = false;
    for (int a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                if (j != 0) {
                    if (valueArray[i][j - 1] == 0  && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i][j - 1] = valueArray[i][j];
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    } else if (valueArray[i][j - 1] == valueArray[i][j] && valueArray[i][j] != 0) {
                        valueArray[i][j - 1] = valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        Score += valueArray[i][j] * 2;
                        valueArray[i][j] = 0;
                        didMove = true;
                        button[i][j].setSize(80, 80);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return didMove;
}
```

Comment: your for loop is not readable and confusing

Comment: Yeah, I mean I could have 4 seperate 4 loops, but the thing is they all do almost the exact same thing, the actual for loops are just a bit different and a couple lines inside. I would cut down on about 75 lines of code by compacting it into 1 method. I could comment to help readability, but is it worth trying to compact it, sacrificing readability?

Comment: make a method with parameters: `i, left, down and right`, return boolean

Comment: I'll post my full methods, give me a sec...

Comment: @Nathan one time I did such a thing in school, and all my teachers were about to kick my butt lol

Comment: Could you provide some background for what you are doing? Maybe there is a more or less complete different solution to this. EDIT: Readability of code is a very important thing in coding (in my opinion)

Comment: @Thomas It is for a 2048 game, it is for calculating cell movements when keys are pressed. It works by(e.g. the right method) starting from the right row and moving to the left, checking each cell as it goes for if it can move right, either via moving into an empty space or merging with an identical cell. Then repeat 4 times because a cell can move from one edge of the board to the other in one key press.

Comment: @KickButtowski, that raises the question of whether its more important to compact your code or keep it readable I guess, I just don't want to take 100 lines to write methods if its easily possible to do it in 25.

Comment: A while ago, I answered this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22545035/3182664 In hindsight, it seemed to be for a 2048 clone (didn't know that back then...). It's at least related, and does the job in 1/2 methods that I personally consider as more readable than yours - yes, that's subjective, but maybe you want to have a look.

Comment: Its possible, I'd have to change the entire structure of my program though and its already finished, just trying to touch it up now... definetly a posibility though

Answer (score 1):

Math; multiplying both sides of the comparison with -1, turns `<=` into `>=`.

```
int sw = Math.abs(Math.signum(right - 1)) * 2 - 1; // -1 when right == 1 else 1

sw*i <= sw*((left*3)+(down*3))
```

Whether this is more optimal or rather cryptoprogramming...

Comment: Thanks!! If the people in the OP comments don't bring up a neater solution, I'll use this